How to make an image grid for matlab
I am having some difficulty with MATLAB and would appreciate your help.
I have a series of values, each of which generates a slice of a large grid that I want to create. I can use MATLAB to visualize each slice individually, but I am unable to generate the grid with all the slices. Could someone help me with this?
The data I have from the images, the first line is 1,1,1,1 and goes up to 2,108,160,16
This is my objective
his is one of the slices I can generate
I want help with a matlab code capable of joining all the slices into a single grid, as shown in the "objective" image.

your explanation is a little vague. it is either that each 2d array like the one you had is a small part of a bigger 2d picture, or it looks like you need to histogram all the 2d array values to get the image. please clarify your question and add some code...

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I'm not too sure what you're looking for but, if you want to create an image grid from individual slices you can arrange each slice into a single large grid using matrix manipulation and plotting functions. I'm going under the assumption that each slice is a 2D matrix which is to be displayed in a grid format.
% Number of rows and columns for the grid
numRows = 4; % Example: 4 rows
numCols = 4; % Example: 4 columns

% Assuming `slices` is a cell array where each cell contains a slice (2D matrix)
slices = {}; % Your slices data should go here

% Example dimensions of each slice (height x width)
[height, width] = size(slices{1});

% Create an empty matrix to hold the full grid
fullGrid = zeros(height * numRows, width * numCols);

% Loop over each slice and place it into the full grid
for i = 1:numRows
    for j = 1:numCols
        % Calculate the starting row and column indices for the current slice
        startRow = (i-1) * height + 1;
        startCol = (j-1) * width + 1;
        
        % Extract the current slice from the cell array
        currentSlice = slices{(i-1)*numCols + j};
        
        % Place the slice into the full grid
        fullGrid(startRow:startRow + height - 1, startCol:startCol + width - 1) = currentSlice;
    end
end

% Display the full grid
imagesc(fullGrid);
axis equal;
colormap gray; % Use grayscale colormap or modify as needed
colorbar; % Display a colorbar if needed
title('Image Grid of Slices');

You just need to set your grid size by altering the numRows and numCols depending on your specification.
Create your empty matrix (fullGrid) to the appropriate size to hold your slices.
Loop over each slice, compute its position in the final grid and insert it into its respective location.
The imagesc just visualizes your grid and the colormap function is used to display the color as shown in your attached link. The colorbar is just there to display the color scale.
If my answer is incorrect just adjust your question or comment on the post and I'll update it.
